# In app purchase "consumable" product type issue IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have developed an IOS app in which we create the calendars dynamically on day to day basis, and users can purchase them.These calendars are of 1 year validity and the events in it expire after 1 year and the user need to repurchase the next series of the calendar.This is our architecture.

We could not find a way to add the product dynamically to itunes. So we chose "coins" to be our in-app purchase product with product type "consumable".If the user wants to buy a calendar then he buys one coin from us and purchases 1 calendar with it.In this way conis are consumed.

Now, the apple suggested to change the product type to "non-consumable".But when  we changed the product type of "coins" to non-consumable, it did not allow us to repurchase the coins.It showed the message "You have already purchased this.Do you want to get it for free?"

So we are confused which product type to choose and how to make it work as per our architecture.

Any guidance, suggestions?

Comment: you can achive this using both non-consumable as well as Non-renewing as suggested below. Non-renewing is self explinatory with examples given by apple. If you want to go with Non-consumable approach. Create dynamic in-app purchases items in code appending year to name of app. e.g. you can say XXX2014 which will point to 2014 license... XXX2015 will point to timeframe of 2015. You can write a webservice on client side which can return this names as well. You need to manually configure them one time in ITunes to be used within your app. But i would recommend to go with below suggestion given

Answer (score 0):

Because a "non-consumable" is a "piece of functionality" (eg: new game levels) that you buy once and could use forever, without the need to buy it again.

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202023), i suggest you a Non-renewing subscription, which looks like matching your needs.